# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user

Tags: codeigniter

I'm attempting to connect my database, but I keep getting this error. I have double checked that I have the correct database name, username, and password.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'kevin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 203

Backtrace:

File: /home1/u3789056/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/u3789056/public_html/system/core/Exceptions.php:271)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 570

Backtrace:

File: /home1/u3790416/public_html/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

I get the error as soon as I add

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'parser');
```

to the config file

Comment: Please include your code; though the first error means you used the wrong password or that  you didn't need to supply a password for mysql. (Just guessing)

Comment: what part of the code would you like me to include? i changed the code and uploaded it to the server again yet i'm still getting the same error, not sure if i should give it some time to update?

Comment: i changed the password*

Comment: You need to include the relevant parts of the code.   If the code is short, then include the whole thing (minus any sensitive information).  If it's long, include relevant parts of the code.